# How to use each term in a .txt file as part of the query when using twitterscraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I'm trying to use [twitterscraper](https://github.com/taspinar/twitterscraper) with python to query tweets however I'm very new to python and kinda unsure where to go with this. I have a .txt file with each term I want as part of the query (there's ~= 100 terms) and they are currently seperated onto a new line each (I can change this to spaces or commas if that's easier), how can I give the query access to these terms and use them to get results? I'm assuming I'll need to put them into some kind of array but I'm unsure if that's correct, and if so, how to do that. Then from there will I need a loop or can i just use the array (or whatever is used) in place of 'query' in the code below?

```
query_tweets('query', limit=None, begindate=dt.date.today(), enddate=dt.date.today(), poolsize=20, lang='')
```

Thanks for any guidance or help you can give.

Edit: Another thing I forgot is in order to search twitter correctly the terms need to have the phrase 'OR' between them, would it make sense to put all the terms into a string with 'OR' between them and just query using the whole string? However, at some point I will be adding functionality where a user can add new terms so I'm unsure how that will work with this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the txt file by doing this:

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as File:
    a = File.read() # Reading the file
```

Then

```
a = a.split(" ") # This is if you want to split words separated by spaces
for i in a:
    query_tweets(i, limit=None, begindate=dt.date.today(), enddate=dt.date.today(), poolsize=20, lang='')
```

So, I tried to describe what I've actual done. Tell me if it's everything ok!

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like what I need, I'll give it a try in a bit. Thanks!